# Create points on the line between speed limit signs near the road in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have a road shapefile (lines) and and speed limit signs (points) near the roads. Now I want to create points on every 5m on the roads between these signs so every single created point should have a speed limit information of a speed for that part of road in that direction (for example if I have a road part between signs where the speed limits are from 60 to 80 and the road direction is from sign 60 to sign 80 all created 5m points should have a speed limit information of 60). Also these points must to contain information of roads too.
This is how I have start working:

1. I have joined line attributes to the signs using join by location
   tool.
2. I have snapped points to the lines
3. I have split the lines on these snapped points.
4. I have created the points on every 5m on these splited lines.

Because I don't have that what I want using my previously described solution I want to know how to solve this using ArcGIS.

Comment: There are now zero questions, so if re-opened it would need to be re-placed on hold because it is unclear what you are asking.  I suggest reviewing https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 which hangs off the [help] which hangs off the [tour].

Comment: @PolyGeo I really hope that is OK now.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried **and where you are stuck trying that**.  If there were a question mark somewhere in your question it would make what you are asking clearer.  What precisely (tools, parameters, etc) have you tried within ArcGIS Desktop to try and achieve what you are aiming for?

Comment: @PolyGeo I am really not sure what is wrong there. I have already asked the questions here without any problems. What is wrong​ with my question now???

Comment: Can you see a question mark anywhere in your question?  If there were one then precisely what you are asking should be clear.  Without one I have read and re-read your question and it comes across as "here's a high level description of what I want to do and some things that I have tried" but nothing about precisely what you were trying to do when in your workflow you got stuck.

Comment: You don't mention using ArcGIS Network Analyst in your question so I removed the tag for that.  I suspect you need to look at Linear Referencing but without being sure what you are asking that is a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: I can't understand what you gain from having points every five meters. This is a uselessly fine interval that would overwhelm any map. Your description states you've accomplished your goal, which makes the purpose of asking the question unclear.

Comment: Do you want to cater for different speed limits per vehicle type, or different speeds in different directions along the road/line?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you have already created points every 5m along your line (let's call this point file), you have a speed limit sign file which has an attribute of "speed", and you have a line file. You have spatially joined your speed limit point file to your line file and your line file is now split at each of these speed limit points. You now want the 5m points showing the speed limit.

May not be the quickest way but: In your joined speed limit to line file add a field in the attributes. Use the field calculator to copy the "speed" attribute. Now your lines show have a speed and you can do the reverse for your 5m points (join to lines, add field, copy speed)